# StackOverFlow exception in getter

Tags: c#, exception, stack-overflow

I'm using the Singleton design pattern and I must return the object if it hasn't been used before. 
I get an exception in the following code :

```
namespace app.Models
{
    public class Conexion:DbContext
    {    
        private static Conexion Instance = null;
        private Conexion(string con) : base(con) { }
        public static Conexion MainConexion 
        {
            get {//error here
                if (Instance == null)
                {
                    Instance = new Conexion(@"Server=*****; User Id=***;Password=****; Database=****");
                }
                return Instance;
            }
        }
        public DbSet<label> Labels { get; set; }
        public DbSet<checke_status> CheckStatus { get; set; }

        public void SaveChanges()
        {
            MainConexion.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
}
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: Why would you use a singleton for a connection?  You'll lose all connection pooling.

Comment: Cuz I just need one instance of that connection and no more. I'll use the connection many times.

Comment: Your `SaveChanges` function will cause a stack overflow. I don't see one in the getter..

Comment: Ah, `SaveChanges` calls the getter, that's probably it.

Comment: Ok, that was the error but, why would a "harmeless" method hurted the hole operation?? I cannot get it.

Comment: You should create a new connection each time, not reuse the one object.  Read up on connection pooling. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8xx3tyca(v=vs.90).aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the override of the `SaveChanges` method:

```
namespace app.Models
{
    public class Conexion : DbContext
    {
        private static Conexion Instance = null;

        private Conexion(string con) : base(con) { }

        public static Conexion MainConexion 
        {
            get
            { //error here
                if (Instance == null)
                {
                    Instance = new Conexion(
                        @"Server=*****; User Id=***;Password=****; Database=****");
                }

                return Instance;
            }
        }

        public DbSet<label> Labels { get; set; }

        public DbSet<checke_status> CheckStatus { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Since you have a private constructor, the only instance of this class that can be used is the one exposed in the `MainConexion` property.  It looks like you were trying to make sure that when any instance's `SaveChanges` method was called that the `SaveChanges` method on the `MainConnection` property's instance was called.  This is not necessary, because you can only ever have one instance of the `Conexion` class, and it's the instance that you want to call `SaveChanges` on.  The usage is still the same:

```
Conexion.MainConexion.SaveChanges();
```

That being said, I think you would have better luck if you were to not implement it this way.  It would probably be better to open and close connections as they were needed, rather than rely on a single connection instance.  What happens if the connection is interrupted?  Rather than getting a single error, your application will be broken.

Comment: "What happens if the connection is interrupted? Rather than getting a single error, your application will be broken." Never thought about that.